# is it possible to make a link a different color in a single achor tag

Tags: html, css

I have a mailto link that I wish to make a separate color than the rest of the links show on the page.  Is this possible?

Im guessing it would look something like:

`<a href="mailto:someone@something.com" style="a: color: White">`

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call inline styles or need to declare id's or classes for selecting `mailto` links, you can use att-val selector like

```
a[href^='mailto:'] {
    color: yellow;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VKZzU/)

Comment: I like this, as I hate adding IDs/Classes to one-off elements. If it's the admin's email (among a list of emails), I'd throw an ID at it. Or... if it's email an addy going to my site (among a list of emails going elsewhere), `a[href*='@something.com'] { color:yellow }`

Comment: @Dawson It's real handy and powerful, why declare unnecessary classes and id's, the moment we start adding ids and classes for such things, document as well as CSS starts bloating

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
style="a: color: White"
```

to

```
style="color: white"
```

Since you're already changing the CSS inline, you don't need a selector. If you were declaring the CSS separately, then you'd use the syntax `a{color:white}`.

Comment: what about changing hover and visited colors?

Comment: You can't use pseudo selectors like hover inline. You have to do those   in a separate style sheet. You should avoid inline CSS whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Give an ID to your A then style it.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@something.com" id="mymailto">
```

Then in your CSS:

```
#mymailto:link {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
<a href="mailto:someone@something.com" style="color:#fff">
```